# Error when trying to create stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a procedure in my SQL Server Management Studio.

I wrote this code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertBookDetails_Sp]
    @BookName  VARCHAR(100),
    @Author    VARCHAR(100),
    @Publisher VARCHAR(100),
    @Price     DECIMAL(18,2),
    @BookPic   VARBINARY(MAX) = NULL, 
AS
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO BookDetails(BookName, Author, Publisher, Price, BookPic)
    VALUES (@BookName, @Author, @Publisher, @Price, @BookPic)
END
```

but it shows error

> Incorrect syntax near 'As'.
>   Invalid ObjectName BookDetails
>   Invalid Column name BookName
>   Invalid Column name Author
>   Invalid Column name Publisher
>   Invalid Column name Price
>   Invalid Column name BookPic

How to solve this error?

Comment: Remove the comma before the AS.

Answer (score 1):

The last parameter should not have ",". Remove the extra "," and try:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertBookDetails_Sp]
@BookName VARCHAR(100),
@Author VARCHAR(100),
@Publisher VARCHAR(100),
@Price DECIMAL(18, 2),
@BookPic VARBINARY(MAX) = NULL
```

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO BookDetails
    (BookName, Author, Publisher, Price, BookPic)
    VALUES
    (@BookName, @Author, @Publisher, @Price, @BookPic);
END